# Cordova build ios doesn't go through and I get no error.

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, cordova-3, cordova-2.0.0

I have problem with apache Cordova and iOS platform. I get stuck at Cordova build with nothing happening other than messages below.

Cordova build iOS --verbose :

```
No scripts found for hook "before_compile".
PlatformApi successfully found for platform ios
Building for iPhone X Simulator
Building project: /Users/ben/Desktop/myApp/platforms/ios/myApp.xcworkspace
    Configuration: Debug
    Platform: emulator
Build settings from command line:
    CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = /Users/ben/Desktop/myApp/platforms/ios/build/emulator
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator12.0
    SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR = /Users/ben/Desktop/myApp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

Build settings from configuration file '/Users/ben/Desktop/myApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig':
    CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES = YES
    CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS = $(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Entitlements-$(CONFIGURATION).plist
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Developer
    ENABLE_BITCODE = NO
    GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = DEBUG=1
    HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/usr/local/lib/include" "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include" "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include" "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)"
    OTHER_LDFLAGS = -ObjC
    SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER = $(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Bridging-Header.h

No scripts found for hook "after_compile".
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Did you found any solution??

Answer (score 4):

This is a cordova issue. Follow this [thread](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/407)

Below code fixed the error for me:-

```
ionic cordova build ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
```

Comment: Thanks, I went back to an older version of Cordova but will try this and accept it as the answer if it fixes the issue.

Comment: mine still facing the same error even with the `--buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"`